PHP: Update global reference variabele inside function scrope
I'm trying to change a global value that is currently a reference to another value. My current implementation doesn't work:
$anna = array('Name' => "Anna");
$bella = array('Name' => "Bella");
$girl = &$anna;

function change(){
    global $girl, $bella;
    $girl = &$bella;
    // $girl['Name'] is now 'Bella'
    output_girl(); // This still outputs 'Anna'
}

function output_girl(){
    global $girl;
    echo $girl['Name'];
}

change();

// What do we want to see?
echo $anna['Name']; // Should still be 'Anna'
echo $bella['Name']; // Should still be 'Bella'
echo $girl['Name']; // Should now be 'Bella' (in above example this will still be 'Anna')

Important notes:

A workaround with a return value like $girl = &change(); is not a solution to my problem. It's important that the global $girl is changed before the end of the change() function. (Reason being this is a problem inside a complex project with nested function calls all wanting to use the same global variables.)
I am aware a workaround could be coded using the $GLOBALS array. However, I am specifically interested if this problem can be solved using the global keyword as seen in the example code. And if not, to know why this isn't possible in PHP.
Removing the &to make it $girl = $bella is also not a solution. The global $girl object needs to always be a reference to the original arrays defined at the start of the script. We cannot ever make copies / break references.

Question: Is this an impossibility in PHP when I use the global keyword? If so, can someone explain why? If not, can someone explain how to make this work?

Remember that the use of global creates a reference to the global variable, not the actual variable.  That might explain what you're seeing.  From the docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references): 'a true global variable imported inside a function scope with the global statement actually creates a reference to the global variable'

@RobEyre You're correct and I am aware. When I create a global variable $foo = 1 and then set it to global $foo; $foo = 2; then the global variable has truly changed. What I'm wondering is why I cannot do this when $foo is a reference to a variable and I want to change what it is referencing.

We cannot ever make copies / break references...why? This seems like a somewhat arbitrary requirement.

I realise this is an existing codebase and it can get complicated...but using globals always  comes with the potential for creating unpredictable chaos and mind-stretching debugging. Can you consider some refactoring? The example you've created is really just some trivial reassignment and echoing so it's difficult to see what the refactoring potential would be. Really your example functions actually just boil down to this: https://3v4l.org/uQT0s. I assume reality is more complex but without seeing a better example it's hard to know where it could be straightened out without breaking anything.

Is it impossible to use objects instead of arrays as your global variables? It works well with objects: https://onlinephp.io/c/f45d2

@ADyson I understand your desire, but this is basically a language question. I wish to find out if the language can do this with the global keyword. Not looking for an alternative way to achieve a similar result.

@MichalHynčica Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately that's not an option for my project. I'm specifically trying to find out if the PHP language is capable of doing this with the global keyword for variables that reference another variable.

I've think you've already shown that it can't be done like this, and I think Rob Eyre and Michal Hynčica have landed on why. And you've already ruled out all the obvious workarounds. So where else do we go for a solution? Unless you simply just want to know the reason, rather than finding some code that will work?

@ADyson My knowledge of PHP isn't 100%, so I'm not yet convinced there's no way to do this. Perhaps there is a way to change what a global reference variable references, that neither I nor you know about. That's my question. My example doesn't "show it can't be done". It merely shows an implementation that doesn't work.

There is no way to obtain a global scope reference using the global keyword. It just provides a new local symbol with the same name, and changing what that local symbol points to cannot change the one in global scope. I don't think there's anything to add to @MichalHynčica's answer, but if you really want to start digging into the PHP source then the global keyword is implemented here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_compile.c#L5398

It's impossible to do that in PHP with only global keyword.
This is because references in php are not same as pointers as we know them for example from C/C++.
When you do $girl = &$anna; on line 3 it doesn't store address of $anna variable in $girl variable. Rather the new symbol $girl is created to reference same variable as symbol $anna.
When you do global $girl, $bella; inside of a function. New local symbols $girl and $bella are created and they are made to reference their global counterpart.
When you do $girl = &$bella; inside the function the local symbol $girl is changed to reference same variable as local symbol $bella but the global symbol $girl is not changed. After doing that both local symbols $girl and $bella are referencing same global symbol $bella.

Thank you! This explained it clearly why the concept of references doesn't allow for this to happen via the global keyword. I really appreciate it!

The problem is that your global is still referencing to $anna.
you can check it by adding print_r($GLOBALS['girl']):
function change(){
    global $girl, $bella;
    $girl = &$bella;
    print_r($girl); //referencing to bella
    print_r($GLOBALS['girl']); //referencing to Anna
    output_girl(); // This still outputs 'Anna'
}

}
I don't know the correct solution for this, but there is a way around it. Just add:
function change(){
    global $girl, $bella;
    $GLOBALS['girl'] = &$bella;
    output_girl(); // now is 'Bella'
}

